# Store object permanently in browser everytime the user inputs anything

Tags: javascript, html, css, object, ecmascript-6

```
let person = {};

document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    const key = document.getElementById('key').value;
    const value = document.getElementById('value').value;
     
    if(key === '' || value === ''){
        alert('Input is invalid');
    }
    else{
        person[key] = value;
    }

    localStorage.setItem('personObj', JSON.stringify(person));
    const retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('personObj');
    console.log(JSON.parse(retrievedObject));

},false);
```

This is my code. What am trying to do is each time the user inputs 2 things it becomes a new property of the person object. The first input being the key and the second one being the value, but what i am not being able to figure out is how can i store those properties permanently in the browser so that whenever user opens the page that property is already there in the object and you don't need to add it again with those inputs. Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: What's the problem with the current code?

Comment: When i reload the page object is showing empty. Whereas i want to have the properties stored permanently

Answer (score 0):

You must load object from local storage after page reload.

```
let person = {};
if (localStorage.getItem('personObj') !== null) {
    person = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('personObj'));
}
```

Data is stored only in local storage. Your code always initialize person variable with empty object. You must initialize it with object from local storage if already exists.

Comment: Are you sure? I forget person variable initialization, check edited answer. Here is working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/5jk80snz/1/

Comment: Why don't you put your fiddle here as a working stack snippet?